# Gtkbuilder connect signals organization

Tags: python, gtk

How can i organize the handlers of my application so that i would not have only one class for my application? To be more precise my application is currently organized in the following way:

```
class main_application(object):
    def handler1(): 
        ...
    def handler2(): 
        ...

    #lots of handlers...


    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("gui.ui") 
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        #build window
        #....
        #tab 1
        #tab 2
        #and etc..

        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.gtk_main_window.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_application()
gtk.main()
```

So my problem is that i want to make make a class for every tab(GtkNotebook)/handler i have for my application but i have a problem when calling self.builder.connect_signals(self), it only connects the signals for my main window and not for the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my problem, instead of using GtkBuilder i used different format of the glade file (libglade) and replaced the connect_signals with signal_autoconnect:

```
def __init__(self): 
        self.gladefile = "gui.glade"
        self.builder = gtk.glade.XML(self.gladefile, "gtk_main_window")
        self.gtk_main_window = self.builder.get_widget("gtk_main_window") 
        self.builder.signal_autoconnect(self)
```